# how to filter out entity object inside entity in rest api

Tags: rest, spring-boot, entity, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot to implement rest api. There are three entities `SeqTb`, `PairTb`, and `GroupTb` and they are nested. `SeqTb` has manytoone with `PairTb`. `PairTb` has onetomany relationship with `SeqTb` and also manytoone with `GroupTb`.

```
//SeqTb.java
@Entity
@Table(name="SEQ_TB")
public class SeqTb implements Serializable {
.......
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PAIR_ID")
    private PairTb pairTb;
......
}

// PairTb.java
@Entity
@Table(name="PAIR_TB")
@NamedQuery(name="PairTb.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PairTb p")
public class PairTb implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID")
    private GroupTb groupTb;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pairTb", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SeqTb> seqTbs;
}

//GroupId.java
@Entity
@Table(name="GROUP_TB")
public class GroupTb implements Serializable {
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PairTb
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="groupTb", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PairTb> pairTbs;
}
```

In my controller GET request with analysisId was handled in the following way:

```
@RequestMapping( 
        value = "/api/seqs/{analysis_id}", 
        method = RequestMethod.GET, 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<SeqTb> getSeqByAnalysisId(@PathVariable("analysis_id") String analysis_id) {
    SeqTb seq = seqService.findByAnalysisId(analysis_id);
    return new ResponseEntity(seq, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I also create a bean class `SeqServiceBean` that extends the interface `SeqService` which in turn calls methods from the following JPA repository for query.

```
//SeqRepository.java
@Repository
public interface SeqRepository extends JpaRepository<SeqTb, Integer> {
    @Override
    public List<SeqTb> findAll();
    public List<SeqTb> findByAnalysisId(String analysisId);
}
```

When I query a SeqTb object with SeqTb.PairTb == null, the api works just fine. However, if the analysisId I put in the url belongs to a `SeqTb` record that associates with a pairId which in turn belongs to a groupId, the program would go nuts. Below is the output, the first part output is correct (bold text). After that it keeps printing PairTb and GroupTb in loops (repeating keywords `pairTb`, `groupTb`).

**{"rowId":8,"analysisId":"cce8d2c2-a6dc-4ee9-ba97-768f058abb50","analyteCode":"D","center":"UCSC",**
*"pairTb"*:{"rowId":4,"pairCode":"01ad975d-c2ed-4e4d-bd3b-c9512fc9073c",*"groupTb"*:{"rowId":1,"groupName":"PAWG_pilot-50",*"pairTbs"*:[{"rowId":1,"pairCode":"00ad0ffe-2105-4829-a495-1c2aceb5bb31",*"groupTb"*:{"rowId":1,"groupName":"PAWG_pilot-50",*"pairTbs"*:

Meanwhile I got lots of errors from tomcat server:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:565) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
```

How do I ignore the nested entity object inside an entity and get only the meaning columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also annotate a property with @JsonIgnore in order to not output that field.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Created a value object that only contains the specific columns from entity and leave out the nested entity object. And it works.